# One npm will work for two different language angular and react?

Tags: reactjs, angular, npm

I started learning React and I read that npm is required to start developing with react, I already installed npm when learning Angular do I still need to install npm again or the first time is enough ?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to install npm a second time, one time is enough.
Angular and React are not languages, they are frameworks and they both use JavaScript or typescript which are basically the same programming language, and that's why npm works with both Angular and React.